# How to show or hide a div if the div is present and has a value

Tags: html, jquery, validation

```
<fieldset class=​"crm-public-form-item crm-group payment_options-group" style=​"display:​ block !important;​ visibility:​ visible;​">​
<div class=​"crm-public-form-item crm-section payment_processor-section" style=​"display:​ block;​">​
  <div class=​"content">    
    ​<input class=​"payment_processor_1 crm-form-radio" value=​"5" type=​"radio" id=​"CIVICRM_QFID_5_payment_processor_id" name=​"payment_processor_id">    
    <input class=​"payment_processor_2 crm-form-radio" value=​"3" type=​"radio" id=​"CIVICRM_QFID_3_payment_processor_id" name=​"payment_processor_id">​
  </div>​
 </div>​
</fieldset>​

<div id=​"crm-submit-buttons" class=​"crm-submit-buttons" style=​"visibility:​ visible;​ display:​ block;​">
​  <button class=​"crm-form-submit default validate crm-button crm-button-type-upload crm-button_qf_Main_upload" value=​"1" type=​"submit" name=​"_qf_Main_upload" id=​"_qf_Main_upload-bottom">​…​</button>​
</div>​
```

[image]

I have this html block and I am bit stuck with validation. Conditions are

- **payment_options-group** fieldset must present on this page
- And **at least one of the radio** button is checked
- Then **show crm-submit-buttons** div
- **Otherwise hide** crm-submit-buttons div

I have tried the following but could not get it to work, also not sure how to define the condition **payment_options-group** fieldset must present on this page. This is important because "crm-submit-buttons" is controlled by other fieldset, which is not present on this page.

```
     if( $("#payment_options-group").val().length === 1 ) {
     $("div#crm-submit-buttons").show();
     }
else {
$("div#crm-submit-buttons").hide();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the length is `> 0` then checkbox is checked and fieldsets is present depending on this show or hide div .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
console.log($(".payment_options-group").length + "--length of fielset")
console.log($("input[name=payment_processor_id]:checked").length + "--length of chekd")
//check if fieldset is prsent and checked length if > 0
if (($(".payment_options-group").length > 0) && ($("input[name=payment_processor_id]:checked").length > 0)) {
  $("div#crm-submit-buttons").show();
} else {
  $("div#crm-submit-buttons").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="crm-public-form-item crm-group payment_options-group" style="display:block !important; visibility: visible;">
  <div class="crm-public-form-item crm-section payment_processor-section" style="display:block;">
    <div class="content">
      <input class="payment_processor_1 crm-form-radio" value="5" type="radio" id="CIVICRM_QFID_5_payment_processor_id" name="payment_processor_id">
      <input class="payment_processor_2 crm-form-radio" value="3" type="radio" id="CIVICRM_QFID_3_payment_processor_id" name="payment_processor_id" checked>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>

<div id="crm-submit-buttons" class="crm-submit-buttons" style="visibility:visible; display:block;">
  <button class="crm-form-submit default validate crm-button crm-button-type-upload crm-button_qf_Main_upload" value="1" type="submit" name="_qf_Main_upload" id="_qf_Main_upload-bottom">​…</button>
</div>
```

Comment: this is your html structure which you have posted ? Also see what console is printing .

Comment: [Log] 1--length of fielset (button.js, line 54)
[Log] 0--length of chekd (button.js, line 55)

from console. When no option is selected. Submit button still visible. HTML is correct. Added screenshot.

Comment: how does code gets called  ? on click of some button?

Comment: No, its a form. Preloaded with all elements. If multiple payment processor is present then "fieldset" is called via JS. If only one Payment processor id present, "fieldset" gets replaced by "billing block", as can be seen from screenshot.

Comment: Working fine check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Le0q5m72/) .Also try wrapping your code inside `$(document).ready..`

Comment: Many thanks, another query was casing problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo with checkboxes that might be easier to understand as you can uncheck to see the button disappear again:

```js
$(".crm-submit-buttons").hide(); // hides button on load 

$('.crm-form-radio').on('click', function() {
  if ($('.payment_options-group').length > 0 && $('.crm-form-radio:checked').length) {
    $(".crm-submit-buttons").show();
  } else {
    $(".crm-submit-buttons").hide();
  }
})
```

```css
fieldset{
  width: 200px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="payment_options-group">
  <input class="crm-form-radio" value="5" type="checkbox" name="payment_processor_id">
  <input class="crm-form-radio" value="3" type="checkbox" name="payment_processor_id">
</fieldset>

<div class="crm-submit-buttons"><button>Button</button></div>
```